# Cannot enter commands using RSE shell in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rse

I am trying to enter commands using the remote system explorer in eclipse.

I have opened a local shell and tried to enter basic commands like `pwd` and `ls`, but nothing happens.

When I press `enter` nothing happens.

I have version 3.4 of RSE installed.